# fetching multiple urls using curl

Tags: php

Need a code example and/or guidance about fetching multiple urls stored in a .txt file using curl. Do I need to use a spider, or can I modify the code below which works well for one url?

```
<?php
$c = curl_init('http://www.example.com/robots.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
?>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: Write a loop that reads a line from the file and uses `curl` to fetch the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but I will try to answer it with the information you provided.

I would use [explode() PHP function](https://www.php.net/explode).

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $page);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $val = explode(':', $line);
    echo $val[1];
}
```

Something like this should do the job.